# ToC links pointing to very same ToC instead of section page

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I have a strange behavior with my ToC using the `hyperref` package. I have nine special paragraphs defined with `\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\[6pt]}` which appears in the ToC (because I set `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`).

The paragraphs are all in different .tex files (branches) which are then `/include{}`d into the main "tree" file. The ToC correctly includes all the paragraphs but strangely, in the pdf, the links from the ToC don't reach the paragraphs but for the last two entries. The first seven entries link back to same page one where the ToC is. On the contrary the last two entries correctly point to their respective pages (actually they point to the paragraph page - 1, but is good enough).

Please consider the following three files:

```
%main.tex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% Subliminal refinements towards typographical perfection
\usepackage{microtype}

% Paragraph indentation
%\setlength{\parindent}{1cm}

% Margins
\usepackage[bottom=2.5cm, top=2cm]{geometry}

% Frame package
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

%Create Hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linktoc=all,
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue;
}

%Create index
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%% Set page layout %%

% Create command for paragraph style (new line after)
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\[6pt]}

%Allow for paragraph in TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}

% Make sentence case all titles
%\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase{#1}}

%% == %%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\include{file1}
\include{file2}
%\include{file3}
%\include{file4}
%\include{file5}
%\include{file6}
%\include{file7}
%\include{file8}
%\include{file9}

\printindex

\end{document}

%file1.tex

\myparagraph{title file 1}

\kant[1-2]

%file2.tex

\myparagraph{title file 2}

\kant[3-4]
```

I can't replicate all the behaviors I experience in my document (with the last two paragraphs being correctly linked from the ToC) but still you will notice that by clicking on the paragraph title in the pdf's ToC you are linked to the very same ToC instead of the paragraph page.

Comment: Please, make a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: Load `hyperref` after `titlesec` in this example.

Comment: @jon That solved the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments ( a long time ago)